# Generic relations missing with grappelli

Tags: django-admin, django-grappelli

I'm using the last svn revision of [grappelli](http://code.google.com/p/django-grappelli/) and rev 11840 of django
(before multidatabases and stuff), and i'm trying to use generic
relations in the admin, but doesn't work,

The model:

```
class AutorProyectoLey(DatedModel):
    tipo_autor = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    autor_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('tipo_autor', 'autor_id')
    proyecto_ley = models.ForeignKey(ProyectoLey)
```

The admin:

```
class AutorInline(GenericInlineModelAdmin):
    model = AutorProyectoLey
    allow_add = True
    ct_field = 'tipo_autor'
    ct_fk_field = 'autor_id'
    classes = ('collapse-open',)
```

And i put this model of var inlines in another adminmodel, but the
html render is :

```
       <!-- Inlines -->






       <!-- Submit-Row -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is necesary for grappelli the fields names content_type and object_id in other way doesn't work.